# Check value In each row datagridview in vb

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview and I want to check a cell value in each rowdatagridview. I take the program in button. So, I click the button and will check the value. If the value from input text equal to the value, will go to next row, if different will still in the row and check the value from input text and will go to the next row if the cell value equal with input text. I'm newbie in vb guys.

I used to play with Arduino. In Arduino, I assume the program like this:

```
If (datagridview1.cell(1).value == textbox.text/input value) {
  i = i++
Else
  i = i 
}
```

Comment: the answer:  
For Each row as DataGridViewRow in yourDataGridView.Rows
    If Not row.Cells(columnName/index).Value = Textbox1.Text Then
       'Set the rows Value to your Textbox.Text/Input Value
       row.Cells(columnName/index).Value = Textbox1.Text
    End If
Next

Answer (score 0):

I think if i have understood your question correctly something like this will help.

```
For Each row as DataGridViewRow in yourDataGridView.Rows
    If Not row.Cells(columnName/index).Value = Textbox1.Text Then
       'Set the rows Value to your Textbox.Text/Input Value
       row.Cells(columnName/index).Value = Textbox1.Text
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank for the answer bro. But,  It will dont care and pass to next row if the value not equal to input value. And i want, if the value not equal will looping check until the value equal with input text then go to next row.

Comment: It will fall into the If statement if the Value isn't equal where you can then set the Value to what you need it to be. I have edited my answer to show this more clearly.

Comment: This is my code like u commend :

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                If Not row.Cells(4).Value = TextBox5.Text Then
                    row.Cells(4).Value = TextBox5.Text
                End If
Next

I want looping my each row datagridview, First is row 0 with checking if row.Cells(1).Value = TextBoxt1.Value Then
MsgBox("Success")
//after success will go to next row,  and checking. If the value not equal 
Else
//in this program i dont know. i want looping check until row.Cells(1).Value = TextBoxt1.Value

Comment: The code i have provided will loop through each row in the DataGridView and if the Value of the Cell matches the TextBox1.Text it will move to the next row and evaluate. If the Value doesn't match then it will set the Value of the Cell to the TextBox1.Text then move the next row.

Comment: hello sir, i have another question in here..
when i weighing my object and value is equal with data so it's true, then when i take off my object and value is 0 or not equal with data it will send.. thank you sir

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by 'it will send' what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks bro i have understand. I have another quetion, how to give report/msgbox when my serialPort is unplug? because when the serialPort is unplug i got error.. thanks